# How to display json and bar chart

Tags: extjs

I have a json data and I will change color dynamically 2 conditions:
condition1: if Color = red, color bar stacked Red
condition2: if color = blue, color bar stacked Blue

My Json is

```
{
"Liste": [
    {
        "Name": "Ligne A",
        "Qte": 150,
        "ListeData": 
        [
          { "OF":"A001",
            "Data":200,
            "Color":"Red"
          },

          { "OF":"A002",
            "Data":400,
            "Color":"Blue"
          },

          { "OF":"A003",
            "Data":800,
            "Color":"Blue"
          }
        ]
    },

]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a custom renderer function to the series config of your chart.

Inside that renderer function you can change the fill config of each bar depending on the color item in your model.

Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

`series: [{
    type: 'column',

    stacked: true,
    renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
       return {
          fill: store.getData().items[index].color
       };
    }
}]`

More info on the series config and the renderer function here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.chart.series.Series.html#cfg-renderer